# (localhost) meta http-equiv don't work on android browsers

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-chrome, localhost

I have a refresh page with javascript and php to submit data to database and return to the main menu page, i'm using localhost with MAMP and it works fine at the desktop, but when i use android browsers to access the localhost project, the function don't work.

```
<body> <?php
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0){
        echo "

            <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost:8885/PCW/login/admin.php'>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Sucess.\");
            </script>
        ";
```

. What i can do to make it work in android browsers? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't meta part of the head?

Comment: Also. Meta redirect works on my page with Android

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: i put on head and didn't work :/ thanks

Comment: i discovered something happen! I'm using my ip to connect on localhost, when the page going to refresh the ip is gone and appears localhost and localhost don't work on android. i don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the Android browser will resolve localhost the same way as your machine. Most machines resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Are you testing this in the Android emulator? If so localhost resolves to 10.0.2.2. Have you tried using that ip when running in an Android browser?

Otherwise, have you tried using the internal IP of the localhost web server rather than localhost?

Comment: i'm not using emulator, i'm running direct on chrome in android. all functions work, only this didn't work

Comment: i discovered something happen! I'm using my ip to connect on localhost, when the page going to refresh the ip is gone and appears localhost and localhost don't work on android. i don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 0):

Meta tag is part of the head.
If you place it in the body as you have, it may or may not work.

Try and move it to it's correct location (in head) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i fixed this changing the localhost on code to my ip. 
So now is this

```
URL=http://0.0.0.0:8885/PCW/login/admin.php'>
```